# i have a file with random numbers. i need to convert all numbers from 2000-4000 to xyzw

Tags: perl

Example input:

```
2234 1233 5678 8876 9009 3444
2222 3454 5667 7878 4554 3222
```

Output:

```
xyzw 1233 5678 8876 9009 xyzw
xyzw xyzw 5667 7878 4554 xyzw
```

I am using this query: `perl -pe 's/^[2-4]+/abcd/g'` but is not giving me the desired output.

Comment: I like the way you phrased the question and provided sample data, but you should also show us what you tried or blocks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's just to run a regular expression, you could do it directly and faster with `sed`:

```
sed 's/\b\([2-3][0-9][0-9][0-9]\|4000\)\b/xyzw/g' input
```

Note that I updated it, considering @roaima's comment.

Comment: @roaima:  Thanks for pointing out that obvious bug.  I'll do a quick fix.